# converting string to int if string has other characters in it

Tags: java, string, int

Hi I have a string "72\n" When I try to use Integer.parseInt("72\n") it gives me a log error, unable to parse'72 ' as integer. What can I do to filter out the \n?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceAll` with an appropriate regex should work well. For instance `\\D` will find all non-numeric characters, and so `myString.replaceAll("\\D", "")` could work well:

```
  String test2 = "72\n";      
  System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", test2);

  test2 = test2.replaceAll("\\D", "");
  System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", test2);
```

This gets trickier if we allow for non-int floating point numbers which allow for locale dependent non-numeric chars such as a single `.` for a decimal point in the usa and `,` in some other locations.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` is the newline character, which among other things is a type of whitespace. Strings in Java have a method called `trim()`, which returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed.

```
String a = "72\n";
String b = a.trim(); // "72"
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to deal with leading and trailing whitespace is to use `String.trim()`.

You could use `replaceAll` or similar to remove embedded whitepace and other "noise", but you run the risk of changing the user's intended meaning.  For instance, an embedded space or comma might have meant that the user thought that he could / should enter multiple numbers.  In my opinion, it is better to tell the user there is an error than it is to try to fix the error and get it wrong (from the user's perspective).

So, in this case I'd say that using `replaceAll` is not a good idea because it is liable to "fix" whitespace within the number as well as leading or trailing it.